# Drop down box not visible

Tags: html, css

When hoovering the menu element a drop down box shall appear. It does but it is cut. Not sure what is wrong here if the Ul nav list cuts it. The drop down menu has been tested ok but not with this menu. I also tried to change the z-index, but without any result. Can you see anything that can inhibit the drop down menu to show?

```js
var navList = document.getElementById("nav-lists");

function Show() {
  navList.classList.add("_Menus-show");
}

function Hide() {
  navList.classList.remove("_Menus-show");
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.container .logo a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.container .navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container .navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.9);
}

.container .navbar ul .close {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul .close span {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar {
  padding: 18px 8px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar i {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .container .logo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container .navbar {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container .navbar ul {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    -o-transition: left .3s;
    transition: left .3s;
  }
  .container .navbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #555555;
  }
  .container .navbar ul .close {
    display: block;
  }
  .container .navbar .icon-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container .navbar ._Menus-show {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.body {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* start of drop down */


/* dropdown css starts here */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0009f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.desc_Info {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* hand over menu item  */


/* END drop down menu */
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Nav bar</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="./index.php"><img src="./bilder/logo2.jpg" alt="Start"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">

      <div class="icon-bar" onclick="Show()">
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
      </div>

      <ul id="nav-lists">
        <li class="close"><span onclick="Hide()">×</span></li>
        <li class="elements">

          <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Cars</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <div class="desc">assadsadsad<br /><br /> asdasdsadasdsadsad
                <br /><br /> adsasdsasaasdasdasdsdasad
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Bikes</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>Hello yes !</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: hidden;` from the `.container`. This cuts off the dropdown.

```js
var navList = document.getElementById("nav-lists");

function Show() {
  navList.classList.add("_Menus-show");
}

function Hide() {
  navList.classList.remove("_Menus-show");
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .logo {
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .logo a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
}

.container .logo a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}

.container .navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container .navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.9);
}

.container .navbar ul .close {
  display: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .navbar ul .close span {
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar {
  padding: 18px 8px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .navbar .icon-bar i {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .container {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .container .logo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container .navbar {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0;
    flex: 0;
  }
  .container .navbar ul {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s;
    -o-transition: left .3s;
    transition: left .3s;
  }
  .container .navbar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #555555;
  }
  .container .navbar ul .close {
    display: block;
  }
  .container .navbar .icon-bar {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .container .navbar ._Menus-show {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.body {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* start of drop down */


/* dropdown css starts here */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0009f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.desc_Info {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* hand over menu item  */


/* END drop down menu */
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Nav bar</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="./index.php"><img src="./bilder/logo2.jpg" alt="Start"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">

      <div class="icon-bar" onclick="Show()">
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
      </div>

      <ul id="nav-lists">
        <li class="close"><span onclick="Hide()">×</span></li>
        <li class="elements">

          <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Cars</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <div class="desc">assadsadsad<br /><br /> asdasdsadasdsadsad
                <br /><br /> adsasdsasaasdasdasdsdasad
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Bikes</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>Hello yes !</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```